# Calculate the five corners of a star - method doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I want to calculate the five corners of a five point star. I set the first point on the top at `x = 0.0` and `y = 1.0`. The first calculation of the second point is correct, because the method takes the value from the points-array.

But the second calculation of the third point doesn't work. Because it takes the value of the first calculation. Maybe there is a problem with the comma when I take a new value from my points-array. --> (. and ,) The value type in the calculation is always double and correct.

The problem: I always get the output 0, 0 of the last three positions of the star corners.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

// draw a 5 point star

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

            double[,] points = new double[5, 2] {
                { 0.0, 1.0 },
                { 0.0, 0.0 },
                { 0.0, 0.0 },
                { 0.0, 0.0 },
                { 0.0, 0.0 }
            };

            // debuging
            // first value?                 correct
            // calculation second value?    correct
            // problem: doesn't take second value to calculation
            //          type --> is always double

            // calculation
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                double[] newVector = RotateVector2d(points[i, 0], points[i, 1], 2.0*Math.PI/5);   // degrees in rad !
                points[i, 0] = newVector[0];
                points[i, 1] = newVector[1];
                Debug.WriteLine(newVector[0] + " " + newVector[1]);
            }

            // drawing
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(myPen, 100, 100, 100 + 50*Convert.ToSingle(points[i,0]) , 100 + 50*Convert.ToSingle(points[i, 1]));
            }

            myPen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }

        static double[] RotateVector2d(double x, double y, double degrees)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("calculating rotation");
            double[] result = new double[2];
            result[0] = x * Math.Cos(degrees) - y * Math.Sin(degrees);
            result[1] = x * Math.Sin(degrees) - y * Math.Cos(degrees);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One word of advice, unrelated to your problem, but you should avoid subscribing to the Form's events from within the Form itself. For example, `Form1_Paint`, You should rather override `OnPaint`. Use the events when another "consumer" is receiving the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to rotate the previous vector instead of the current one:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    double[] newVector = RotateVector2d(points[i - 1, 0], points[i - 1, 1], 2.0*Math.PI/5);   // degrees in rad !
    points[i, 0] = newVector[0];
    points[i, 1] = newVector[1];
    Debug.WriteLine(newVector[0] + " " + newVector[1]);
}
```